# Explicit solutions for advection-diffusion PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In order to test some implementations of numerical solvers for advection-diffusion equations with non-constant coefficients, I'm looking for examples of equations+border and initial conditions of this type which have explicit solutions. Could you propose any or references to such?

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest you the following studies where you can find the exact solution of the numerical examples.

1) Vit Dolejsi, hp-DGFEM for nonlinear convection-diffusion problems, 
   http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.matcom.2013.03.001

2) Melanie Bittl, Dmitri Kuzmin, Roland Becker, The CG1-DG2 method for convection–diffusion equations in 2D, http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2014.03.008

3) Tie Zhang, Ying Sheng, Superconvergence and gradient recovery for a finite volume element method for solving convection-diffusion equations, DOI: 10.1002/num.21862

I hope they will work...

Best wishes...

Answer (score 2):

The method of manufactured solution is very simple. If you have your system $F(u)=0$, then you let your solution be e.g. $u=\sin(x^2)+\cos(\exp(y))$, plug into $F$ to get $F(u)=g(x,y)$. Now $F_0=F(u)-g=0$ is your new equation with solution $u$ and corresponding BC.

Comment: What about boundary conditions?

Comment: If you have Dirichlet BC then they are equal to the solution $u$ at the boundary, e.g. $u_{x=0}(y)=u(0,y)$.